# Replaying events using rxjs. Or how to use rxjs with tick-time instead of wallclock-time

Tags: rxjs, observable, reactive-programming

I'm looking into using reactive programming, specifically [rxjs](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/overview), for building logic on top of large event streams I need to process.

This involves doing a lot of time-related stuff such as generating a synthetic event every second. (contrived example)

When events come in in real-time (i.e. events are processed using wallclock time), this is easily solved with [merging](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/merge) an interval-source into the eventstream. From said link:

```
    // RxJS v6+
    import { mapTo } from 'rxjs/operators';
    import { interval, merge } from 'rxjs';

    //emit every 2.5 seconds
    const first = interval(2500);
    //emit every 2 seconds
    const second = interval(2000);
    //emit every 1.5 seconds
    const third = interval(1500);
    //emit every 1 second
    const fourth = interval(1000);

    //emit outputs from one observable
    const example = merge(
      first.pipe(mapTo('FIRST!')),
      second.pipe(mapTo('SECOND!')),
      third.pipe(mapTo('THIRD')),
      fourth.pipe(mapTo('FOURTH'))
    );
    //output: "FOURTH", "THIRD", "SECOND!", "FOURTH", "FIRST!", "THIRD", "FOURTH"
    const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

However, I often need to replay eventstreams, and also merge synthetic events into this stream in proper order. I.e.: each event has a timestamp and the synthetic event needs to be correctly placed in the eventstream so that the timestamps of the resulting merged eventstream keeps (monotonically) increasing. (i.e. events are processed using tick time)

This is a specific case of the more generic problem of merging N eventstreams in tick-time order.

Ideally, I would write the reactive-logic irrespective of wallclock-time or ticktime. Then I would initialize rxjs with some context denoting we're either in wallclock-time or tick-time, and if the latter, point to the event-property which carries the timestamp. Rxjs would sort out the rest, without needing to handle the difference in custom code.

Any pointers much appreciated

Comment: Are you looking to replay these streams with the same amount of time inbetween original emissions?  Is your main challenge inserting the synthetic event in the correct place in the stream?

Comment: I'd like to replay the stream as fast as possible, so tracked time is much faster than wallclock-time. Yeah, placing the synthetic event in the correct place while doing it elegantly is my biggest challenge. With elegant here I mean, having all (most) of my logic being ignorant whether code is being replayed, or live

Comment: Are the synthetic events still generated 1 per wall-clock second? EDIT: I see, 1 per "second" but not real-time.

Comment: Seems your biggest hurdle to achieving context-agnostic reactive logic is the backpressure you have to contend with in the tick-time case.

Comment: Are you using the [VirtualTimeScheduler](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/so-what-is-rxjs-virtualtimescheduler-796e92ed722f)?

Comment: @NickL: That's pretty close to what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @Geert-Jan Did you figured it out? i'm running similar into issue

Comment: @Dams no didn’t use rxjs in the end.

Comment: @Geert-Jan may i ask how you handled the use case then ?

Comment: @Dams: I used the following code as inspiration, which combines 2 or more async iterators and creates a new async iterator as a result: https://github.com/tardis-dev/tardis-node/blob/master/src/combine.ts. The code transparently allows for realtime and historic events

Comment: @Geert-Jan We're working on exactly same problematic, thanks for the snippet, i actually already had a look at this library :)

Comment: @Dams I'm pretty sure this narrows down the domain :). Good luck out there!

Comment: @Geert-Jan it definitely does! Good job on tardis btw! Thank you and i'll see you in the book :)

Comment: @dams oh Tardis is nog mine but it’s definitely a nice lib. See you there ;)